# How to get values that match on id with the other table that has been imported?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to get values that match on `ID` with the other table that has been imported? I basically want to import bank details from other table via `ID` and I want to display it next to the `companyName` that on the same `ID` the `bankName`.

I have tried few options but nothing seem to work.

Thank you and please keep it simple because I'm still learning :)

**Interfaces**:

```
export interface Company {
  id: number;
  companyName: string;
  address: string;
  estimatedRevenue: number;
}

export interface Bank {
  id: number ;
  bankName: string;
  bankAccountNumber: string;
}
```

**Component**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from '../_models/company';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';
import { CompanyService } from '../_services/company.service';

import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { AddCompanyComponent } from '../add-company/add-company.component';
import { Bank } from '../_models/bank';
import { BankService } from '../_services/bank.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companies.component.css'],
})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCompany: Company;
  companies: Company[];
  banks: any;
  selectedCompanyBank: Bank[];
  bankvalueid: number;
  bankNameany;
  bankName: string;

  constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private bankService: BankService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCompanies();
  }

  async loadCompanies() {
    this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe(
      (companies: Company[]) => {
        this.companies = companies;
      },
      error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      },
    );
  }

  async loadBanks() {
    this.bankService.getBanks().subscribe(
      (banks: Bank[]) => {
        this.banks = banks;
      },
      error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      },
    );
  }

  //  companyChange() {
  //    this.bankName = this.banks.find((bank) => bank.id ===
  //     this.selectedCompany.id).bankName;
  // }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="selectCompanyDiv">
  <ng-container *ngIf="companies">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
      <label for="">Select Company</label>
      <!-- <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="bankvalueid" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany"> -->
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany">
        <option *ngFor="let each of companies" [ngValue]="each">{{
          each.companyName
        }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <br />
  <br />

  <ul *ngIf="selectedCompany" class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Company name: {{ selectedCompany.name }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Company address: {{ selectedCompany.address }}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Company Estimated revenue: {{ selectedCompany.estimatedRevenue }}₪
    </li>
    <button>Show more information</button>
  </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedCompany" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ selectedCompany.companyName }} {{ bankName }}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">Location: {{ selectedCompany.address }}</h6>
    <br />
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">
      Estimated revenue: {{ selectedCompany.estimatedRevenue }}₪
    </h6>
    <p class="card-text">
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Edit Information</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!--
<h4>Basic native select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select Company</mat-label>
  <select  matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let value of companies" [ngValue="value"]{{value.name}}></option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
-->
```

Comment: Do you mean based on bankvalue id you want to get data from the variable banks?

Comment: I mean if i have same Company id and same bank id and i so basically its a match and i want to display the bank name next to the company i just have no idea how to do this

Comment: please include the model files of company and bank

Comment: Add i can upload the whole project to git-hub if you want too =/

Comment: no no..this is enough

Comment: Your question has a lot of duplicate markup. Can you please reduce the noise and focus on what you want, so we could understand the question? Also, I noticed that you've two `ngModel` for `select` and unnecessary `async` in your `functions`.

Comment: i know ive tried to do few things forgot to delete i will re-upload now

Comment: Why are you using `async` in functions? And it seems that you aren't calling `loadBanks` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngModelChange

HTML:

```
<select  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" (change)="companyChange()">
```

And to display bank name to side of company name:

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{selectedCompany.companyName}} {{bankName}}</h5>
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">Location: {{selectedCompany.address}} </h6>
```

In TS:

Declare an instance variable bankName

```
bankName:string; 

ngOnInit() { 
   this.loadCompanies(); 
   this.loadBanks() ;
}

companyChange(){
if(this.banks.length>0){
 this.bankName=this.banks
 .find((bank)=> bank.id == selectedCompany.id).bankName;
 } 
}
```

Example in js:

```js
this.banks=[
   {
     bankName:"CITI",
     id:1
   },
   {
     bankName:"HDFC",
     id:2
   }
];
let selectedCompany={
   companyName:'Example Company',
   id:2
}
let bankName=this.banks.find((bank)=> bank.id ==  selectedCompany.id).bankName; 
console.log(bankName);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Umm it dosnt seem to work where should i place it exactly ?

Comment: Ive changed the answer

Comment: Ok lets check it out

Comment: not working =/ i did exactly the same like you said

Comment: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at CompaniesComponent.companyChange (companies.component.ts:58)
    at CompaniesComponent_ng_container_1_Template_select_ngModelChange_4_listener (companies.component.html:8)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21697)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21746)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:36917)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
...

Comment: lets check it out

Comment: it seems companyChanged is getting called before banks and company data are loaded.

Comment: bankName=this.banks.find((this.banks).bank.id==this.selectedCompany.id).bankName; in TS but still now working getting error core.js:5871 ERROR Error: Uncaught

Comment: I've edited the answer. In ngOnInit call loadbanks . Thanks to @developer033

Comment: still not working ..... https://github.com/Chentamayev/OnSoft.git if you want